# Use SSL for Apache and Spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

There is already a SSL certificate installed which covers the whole Apache `/var/www/html` folder and works fine for all https://www.example.com/allpathes/

Now a Spring Boot project is coming online on port 8070, the SSL is also installed and it does work on https://www.example.com:8070/springbootpath/.

However, the port 8070 should be hidden and because of apache, visiting the spring boot project without the port redirects to an empty apache directory saying

> The requested URL /springbootpath/ was not found on this server.

What exactly do I need to set in the VIRTUALHOST config?